# chrome:// Invalid Scheme

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've enabled "chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls" which should allow me to create extensions that can run on chrome:// sites. When I try to unpack my extension, however, it fails with the error message: "Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Invalid scheme." I don't believe my script.js is a problem since the unpacking doesn't fail when I replace the "chrome://extensions" part with an http or https sites. Any help would be greatly appreciated, does anyone know a fix?

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Does something on chrome://extensions",
  "version": "1.2",
  "description": "Read the name",
  "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Ext",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["chrome://extensions"],
    "js": ["script.js"]
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Note: This is an undocumented feature and may fail without warning in the future.**

`chrome://extensions` *is* an invalid match pattern. You cannot omit the path component, so at the very least you should use `"chrome://extensions/*"`.

This does however not work either, because the actual URL is `chrome://chrome/extensions`. Or, if you are specifically interested in the page that shows the list of extensions, `chrome://extensions-frame`.

To run a content script at the extensions page, use `--extensions-on-chrome-urls` and:

```json
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["chrome://chrome/extensions*"],
    "js": ["script.js"]
  }]
```

or (the frame that lists all extensions, i.e. what you see when you visit `chrome://extensions`):

```json
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["chrome://extensions-frame/*"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": ["script.js"]
  }]
```