# How to run content script only on my extension generated page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

how to run content scripts on a specific page which is hosted my extension

I've tried this

```
 "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["chrome-extension://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["script.js"],
    "all_frames": true
  }],
```

but it throws an error

```
Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Invalid scheme.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747941/chrome-invalid-scheme ?

Comment: that's in 2017 and Is there a stable solution to solve this problem in 2020?

Comment: Content scripts are for web pages. There's no need to use them on your own page because you can use a standard `<script src=file.js></script>` in your extension page html.

Comment: There is a specific use case for me to run the content script on my extension page.

Comment: @James that solution is not working anymore

Comment: I'll try to rephrase. The mechanism of content scripts can't be used here and there's no need for that because there's a standard mechanism for loading scripts in html.

Comment: My use case is I need to inject script inside iframe where iframe loaded inside chrome extension hosted page. Is there an alternative way to achieve this? @wOxxOm

Comment: In that case it all depends on the iframe's URL. Currently `matches` covers `https` but if your frame is `http` then you should add it too or just use `*://*/*`

Comment: the point is your solution will work but the script will be injected on every page I only want that to be injected to my chrome extension hosted page @wOxxOm

Comment: Of course, that's how content script matching works. The usual workaround for such cases is to add a dummy parameter to the URL of the frame and match it like `*://*/*&foo*`

Comment: `*://*/*&foo*` this is not working for me.I've tried this `*://*/*foo*` so when I redirect a user to this page `chrome-extension://extension_id/foo.html` I thought `foo` might match the pattern and trigger the content script but it works only works on HTTP/HTTPS protocols @wOxxOm

Comment: I am thinking of running content_script on all pages and matches the URL pattern inside content_script and execute the js functions. I think this is the only solution available right now 

Comment: This is not how content script matching works. It applies to the URL of the frame, not to the host page. You seem to be misunderstanding what I suggest, but I can't really help without seeing an [MCVE](/help/mcve).